# Magento Dispatching events in templates

Tags: php, magento

**Desired Logic**

I would like my template to dispatch an event every time the user clicks the
on and off buttons.
My view.phtml file look likes this...

```
/*Some Html*/ 


<?php
/*=== Variables ===========*/
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/session')->getCustomer();
/*$groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();*/
$groupId = $customer->getGroupId();
$group = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId);
$groupCode = $group->getCode();

$OnArray = array(
   "value" => "on", 
   "customer" => $customer
    );
$OffArray = array(
   "value" => "off", 
   "customer" => $customer
    );
?>

  /* More HTML * /  

<form action="">
    <input type="radio" name="auto-refill" value="On" onClick = "<?php Mage: dispatchEvent('autoFill_Update', $OnArray ?>" />On<br>
    <input type="radio" name="auto-refill" value="Off" onClick = "<?php Mage: dispatchEvent('autoFill_Update', $OffArray ?>" />Off
</form>
```

**Questions**

Did I implement the desired logic correctly ?

Since the php scripts are separated my html code do I lose the
 reference to the ON and OFF arrays when I try to pass them in onClick ?

**Any guidance is truly appreciated**

Comment: Hi Ryan, you can't trigger PHP events once the page has loaded like that. You'll need to use Javascript to trigger an AJAX request to a controller, and from there you can trigger your event.

Comment: @scrowler Thanks for the help. If I understand this correctly, the onclick element will pass the Javascript trigger.  Inside the trigger utilize an AJAX requeest that will pass the data to my controller in magento.. Is this correct ?

Comment: Yep, that's correct. Then your Mage controller will dispatch the event depending on the data that the AJAX request sends through from your template.